# Is my code to change the CSS of an element when clicked efficient?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to change the CSS of multiple elements when one is clicked.

I have working code whereby clicking on a subheading within the "About" section changes its color, the color of the other subheadings, and the opacity of reach respective paragraph. It looks like a lot of code to me. I imagine there is a simpler or at least more streamlined way to accomplish these things that I just don't know with my borderline intermediate JS skills.

```js
const about = () => {
  const paraOne = document.getElementById("para-one");
  const paraTwo = document.getElementById("para-two");
  const paraThree = document.getElementById("para-three");
  const mission = document.querySelector(".mission");
  const value = document.querySelector(".value");
  const vision = document.querySelector(".vision");
  mission.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mission.classList.add("active");
    value.classList.remove("active");
    vision.classList.remove("active");
    paraOne.classList.remove('zero');
    paraTwo.classList.add('zero');
    paraThree.classList.add('zero');
  });
  value.addEventListener('click', () => {
    value.classList.add("active");
    mission.classList.remove("active");
    vision.classList.remove("active");
    paraOne.classList.add('zero');
    paraTwo.classList.remove('zero');
    paraThree.classList.add('zero');
  });
  vision.addEventListener('click', () => {
    vision.classList.add("active");
    mission.classList.remove("active");
    value.classList.remove("active");
    paraOne.classList.add('zero');
    paraTwo.classList.add('zero');
    paraThree.classList.remove('zero');
  });
}

about();
```

```css
#about-center ul li:hover,
#about-center ul li.active {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
}

.zero {
  opacity: 0;
}

#about ul,
#about p,
#about button {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#about-center p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="about-center">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="mission active">OUR MISSION</li>
    <li class="value">our values</li>
    <li class="vision">our vision</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="para-one">This is our mission.
    </p>
    <p id="para-two" class="zero">These are our values.
    </p>
    <p id="para-three" class="zero">This is our vision.
    </p>
  </div>
  <button>read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I would have chosen a wrapping element (`#about-center` in this case) and swapped out classes on that. Rather than having six of `.add`/`.remove` for each state, you'd just have the three for each state. With a little more wrangling, you could bring that down to one.

Comment: Piggybacking off of @Ouroborus, the more "general" (less specific/nested) you can keep your code, the more efficient and easier to maintain it will be. Applying this concept looks like doing what Ouroborus suggested in this case, and maybe even thinking about a CSS pre-processor like SASS (https://sass-lang.com/) to keep your styles organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all the `li` elements. Use this to add the event listeners initially. Then in the listener, you can loop again to do the appropriate class changes for the element that the user clicked on versus the other elements. And you can use the index of the iteration to change the class of the corresponding `p` element.

```js
const about = () => {
  const lis = document.querySelectorAll("#about-list li");
  const paras = document.querySelectorAll("#container p");
  lis.forEach(li => li.addEventListener("click", (e) => lis.forEach((li1, index) => {
    if (li1 == e.target) {
      li1.classList.add("active");
      paras[index].classList.remove("zero");
    } else {
      li1.classList.remove("active");
      paras[index].classList.add("zero");
    }
  })));
}

about();
```

```css
#about-center ul li:hover,
#about-center ul li.active {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#about-center ul li {
  color: grey;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
}

.zero {
  opacity: 0;
}

#about ul,
#about p,
#about button {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#about-center p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="about-center">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
  <ul id="about-list">
    <li class="mission active">OUR MISSION</li>
    <li class="value">our values</li>
    <li class="vision">our vision</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="para-one">This is our mission.
    </p>
    <p id="para-two" class="zero">These are our values.
    </p>
    <p id="para-three" class="zero">This is our vision.
    </p>
  </div>
  <button>read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Brrr... why add many event listeners? In the contrary, what they need is delegation.

Comment: That's another way to do it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I don't think I would have ever come up with that. I knew there needed to be a `forEach()` somewhere. I just didn't know exactly where and how. I appreciate everyone's time. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as effective as it could be. Now, there are things which can be done to make it more readable (especially if you get more than three tabs later), but that won't change the effectiveness or would actually make it worse.

Like ... it would be more readable to make function which will turn "off" all tabs and call it from all click handlers, although technically it means it will be needlessly removing class which is not set on one of them.

Also, if you put the matching paragraphs IDs into HTML, you can use just one function for all and use event.currentTarget to recognize which one it was called for. Again, not worth the time if you have just three tabs, but if you have more ...